# Start process and access the "shell" at a later time

Tags: process, tmux, gnu-screen, process-management

I have a remote testing machine which is experiencing some failures. What I would like to do is trigger a `gdb` process upon failure on the remote machine, and then `ssh` into the remote machine and access the existing `gdb` process. Is there a way to "reseat" an existing process into my current shell, given `sudo` privileges and the pid of the process? Or something similar; to be clear I'm aiming to have full `stdin`/`stdout` access as if I had just started that process from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

The tool you want is `screen` or `tmux`. I prefer `screen`. (I thought this would be duplicate but I can't find a relevant one.)

Log on to the remote system and then launch screen

```
screen
```

You'll get a new shell, and now you can start your `gdb process. Use <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl D</kbd> to detach from the session and logout.

Later you can reattach. Log back on to the remote system

```
screen -r                  # Reattach to a single detached screen
```

Some other simple but useful options

```
screen -ls                 # List the available screens (detached or attached)
screen -S sessionname      # Create a new screen session with identifier "sessionname"
screen -r <identifier>     # Reattach to a named detached screen
screen -dr <identifier>    # Forcibly detach an attached screen and attach to it
```

Comment: Just a heads-up that the way this question is phrased, the OP wants to *trigger* the gdb session on process failure.  So still agree on `tmux` or `screen` (I prefer `tmux` ;-)) but the multiplexor itself would need to be launched by the signal handler.  I'd recommend making it something like a `tmux new-session -s gdb ...` (`screen -S gdb ...`) to name the session so that it can be easily reattached (`tmux attach gdb`/`screen -S gdb`) through `ssh`.